# Word 2010 - page break before H2 except after H1

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I've got a word document with more or less the following structure:

```
Title
Heading 1
  Heading 2
    Text
  Heading 2
    Text
Heading 1
  Heading 2
    Text
...
```

I'd like page breaks before all H2 headings, *except* the ones directly after H1 headings, when I'd prefer the two headings to be on the same page.

I know I can automatically set "page break before" in the style for Heading 2, but is there some way I can set an "except directly after Heading 1" option without having to add all the page breaks manually?

In other words, I'd like the breaks as follows:

```
Title
-- Page Break --
Heading 1
  Heading 2
    Text
-- Page Break --
  Heading 2
    Text
-- Page Break --
Heading 1
  Heading 2
    Text
-- Page Break --
  Heading 2
    Text
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new style will accomplish what you want. Try this procedure:

1. Use the **Paragraphs dialog box** to make `Word` insert a page break before all **Heading 2** text.
2. Create a new style, **"Heading 2 Prime"**, that's exactly like **Heading 2**, but uncheck the **"page break before"** option. Be sure you spell **"Heading 2 Prime"** exactly as written here.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the `VBA development environment`, then click **"Insert > Module"** to open a new window for entering programs.
4. Paste the following statements into the window. These statements replace all **Heading 2** paragraphs that come after **Heading 1** paragraphs, with the **Heading 2 Prime style**.

Code to paste:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub replace_Heading2_with_Heading2Prime()

Dim i As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim h As String

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'loop through all pgp and report heading 2

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

s = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style

If (s = "Heading 2") Then
 h = findPriorHeading(i - 1)
 If (h = "Heading 1") Then
 ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style = "Heading 2 Prime"
 End If
End If

Next i

Exit Sub

End Sub

Function findPriorHeading(iPgp As Integer) As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim blnFoundHeading As Boolean
'walk backwards until any heading is found
 With ActiveDocument
 i = iPgp
 blnFoundHeading = False
 Do Until (i < 1 Or blnFoundHeading)
 s = .Paragraphs(i).Style
 If (InStr(s, "Heading") > 0) Then
 blnFoundHeading = True
 findPriorHeading = s
 Exit Function
 End If
 i = i - 1
 Loop
 End With
 findPriorHeading = ""

End Function
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to return to `Word`, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to open the Macros dialog box. Double click the **"replace_Heading2_with_Heading2Prime"** item to run the macro.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you try cleaning up your example code? I would but I can't figure out where things should be broken up. Try using the editor buttons at the top of the text box to make code blocks out of the sample code.

Comment: Sorry about the ugly code. I've cleaned up the formatting. All of the content with the grey background, which is all of the bold text, is code. Select all of that, and just that, and paste it into the VBA editor as the instructions indicate.

Comment: While not exactly what I was hoping for, this works (and suggests that there is no simple checkbox solution for this) so +1.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

1. Tick the box for "Page break before" in the style properties for H2,
2. For each instance of H1, go to its associated "x.1", i.e. the first instance of H2, open paragraph properties and manually untick the box for "Page break before".

Just like Darrin Koltow solution in this thread, this has its pros (no need for a separate style) and cons (still requires some manual work), and it is clearly a matter of preference.

I really cannot see why this is not a built-in feature though. I've managed to find [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/o365guy/2018/01/02/submit-product-feedback-or-feature-requests-to-microsofts-virtual-suggestion-boxes/) and [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11) to prove uservoice is the official channel for requests, but don't have time atm to look into this further.